# Cannot convert float NaN to intger

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the following code snippet to work -

```
r,c,_ = img1.shape
  for r, pt1, i in zip(l, inpts2, range(len(inpts2))):
      color=(0,128,128)
      x0,y0 = map(int, [0, -r[2]/r[1]])
      x1,y1 = map(int, [c, -(r[2]+r[0]*c)/r[1]])
      img1 = cv2.line(img1, (x0,y0), (x1,y1), color ,4)
      img1 = cv2.circle(img1, (int(inpts2[i][0]), int(inpts2[i][1])), 5, (0,200,255), 5)
  plt.imshow(img1)
  plt.show()
```

But I get this error

[image: error]

Please let me know how I can correct this error. This same piece of code is working in another function in my code.

Comment: Can `r[1]` be 0?

Comment: if `r[1]` is `0` there would be `division by zero` error

Comment: it is. How can I deal with this exception? Thanks

Comment: `r[1]` is just the divisor and it can probably be cast to 1 for `NaN` values.

Comment: Within numpy, dividing by 0 is not necessarily a "division by zero error". For example, when there's only `import numpy as np` and `print(np.abs(0)/np.abs(0))`, there's no such error, just "Runtimewarning", and it continues after printing `nan`